# Is the module trax.fastmath deprecated?

Tags: python, trax

Is the module trax.fastmath of TRAX package deprecated?  I am using this module, but ModuleNotFoundError is returned.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the package correctly? [The package is imported in `__init__.py`](https://github.com/google/trax/blob/master/trax/__init__.py#L19), so you should be able to import it in your workspace

Comment: I have used from trax.fastmath import numpy as fastnp.  Is this right?  Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have `numpy` installed? The `trax` documentation seems to indicate it is a dependency.

Comment: Yes, I do have numpy installed correctly.  I am wondering what the source of error could be.  Really bemusing.

Comment: One quick question:  I simply used "pip install trax" which installed version Trax 1.3.7.  Am I doing it right?

Comment: Dependencies should be installed as well. Can you import trax itself?

Comment: Hi all, I replaced trax.fastmath with trax.math and it worked perfectly.  It's a bit crazy, but this has not been updated in the Trax documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced trax.fastmath with trax.math and things worked perfectly fine.  I am still not sure if this has been updated in the Trax documentation.